# Cannot get Django 1.7 Migrations to detect proper changes to my DB.

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a production web project running with a decent amount of data in the MySQL db. I am trying to update the database with some changes to an app called "enterlink." I've made new elements in the existing models and created new models altogether. Before this migration, I have never touched the schema of the db since originally running syncdb to create it. When I run: "python manage.py makemigrations enterlink" the below output appears(pic). My question is, why is this happening? The DB already includes all the models that it lists in the picture so why is it registering those lists of models? When I go to finish the migration by doing "python manage.py migrate" or "python manage.py migrate --fake enterlink" (pic again), I get an output shown but my database schema remains identical to the old db and any new code generates errors. Can anyone tell me what is likely the problem? I would be really appreciative of any advice. It's been very frustrating since I'm not sure what I'm missing.

[image: What the output looks like when I makemigrations my enterlink app]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have done is that you have ran the command `python manage.py syncdb`  before running `python manage.py makemigrations myapp` and `python manage.py migrate myapp`. That is why `syncdb` created the database schema and the migration was faked because schema already exists. I will suggest to use `python manage.py makemigrations myapp` and `python manage.py migrate myapp` and not to use `syncdb` as its deprecated in Django 1.7.

If you change anything in your model, just run `makemigrations` and `migrate` command. Syncdb isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I only did syncdb for the very first db creation of the app. Now that I can't start over because I have already a large amount of data in my rows, what can I do? I have tried doing makemigrations myapp and migrate myapp like you suggest, but none of those two commands currently creates the new tables I need. Are you suggesting I need to do some housekeeping on my DB before I try to update my models.py file and start the migration process?

Comment: If I were you, I would first backup my current database(dumpdata), then create a new database, run `makemigrations` and `migrate`, then import the dumpdata to the new database. @SwAvGuy . Making new db necessarily doesn't mean to drop database, just create a new one with different name, and test if it works for you, then do what you see most suitable. :)

Comment: I'll try that and update if it works. Thanks for your suggestions. But just curious, the way that I am understanding you correctly is that the problem is arising because Django has not created an initial migration schema for my first database configuration because I used syncdb? Is this the probably source of error?

Answer (score 2):

This question and relevant answers are intriguing me. Thus I want to share my experience on maintaining live database and migrations.

Tested in django1.5.5

## Initializing the database:

1. `./manage.py syncdb  --noinput`
2. `./manage.py migrate`
3. `./manage.py syncdb`

Now I have created the database.

## Doing a migration for an app:

1. `./manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial`
2. `./manage.py migrate myapp --fake`
3. Now do necessary changes in your model
4. `./manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto`
5. `./manage.py migrate myapp`

Comment: Hey thanks for your input! I've since figured it out well for my production build, but this is a very helpful post with someone with similar problems as me looking for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Im newbie for schemamigration too, but i will explain how it works for me:

**First** you create  app and then 
    ./manage.py sycndb, so tables are created then you can 
    ./manage.py makemigrations myapp --initial
so now initial migrations are created and you should apply them
    ./manage.py migrate myapp
**now you can change your models** : add,change fields, anything you want and then
    ./manage.py makemigrations myapp --auto
this will create migrations for changes and now you need to apply them
    `enter code here`./manage.py migrate myapp
so this actually will create new tables in db

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if I'm understanding you correctly, you are saying before I update the models.py file with the new models.py file with the changes to my model and DB, I need to first makemigrations --myapp --initial before I do anything else? After I do that, only then should I switch the models.py file and try to change the DB structure?

Comment: first of all backup files/database

Comment: then ./manage.py makemigrations myapp --initial    then ./manage.py migrate myapp then make changes then ./manage.py makemigrations myapp --auto and apply ./manage.py migrate myapp