# Updating the models in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, models

Initially my model looked something like this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
class blogpost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.TextField()
    createdon = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I applied makemigrations and then migrate to this model. Now, I wanted to remove the field slug from this model. I removed it and then applied makemigrations.

```
^C(mysite)shivam@shivam-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/Python/django/mysite/mysite$ python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'blog':
  0003_remove_blogpost_slug.py:
    - Remove field slug from blogpost
```

But now when I apply migrate, it gives me an error.

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, blog, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying blog.0003_remove_blogpost_slug...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 121, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.remove_field(from_model, from_model._meta.get_field(self.name))
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 438, in remove_field
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 112, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/shivam/Python/django/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1091, "Can't DROP 'slug'; check that column/key exists")
```

What should I do to remove the slug field?

Comment: Which version are you using? Is there anything else? I tried you code and nothing happened but remove successfully.

Comment: One way you could solve this IF you are in development still, you can delete the `blogpost` table, because all the blogposts that you have saved already have slugs, or you can just delete the column slugs from the `blogpost` table. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: @shellbye it removed successfully because you don't have any data before you tried to remove the slug. If you create a `blogpost` with a slug and then try to remove the `slug` field, you will get the same error.

Comment: Please show `0003_remove_blogpost_slug.py`

Comment: @qasimalbaqali I used Django 1.9 and even I created some `blogpost`, it still been moved successfully and the database updated, too.

Comment: When I check the tables through mysql, slug doesn't exist there but migrate still doesn't know about it .

Comment: Here is my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061249/cannot-get-django-1-7-migrations-to-detect-proper-changes-to-my-db/28062087#28062087